# Adding elements to a list in order?

Tags: list, sorting, python-2.5

I am trying to initialize a list using integers read from a file. Each time I read an integer I add an element to the list (the element defined by a calculate() function), and the index the element is added at is the integer I read. So if I read "5", I want an element stored at index 5. The integers in the file are out of order numerically, so I can't simply insert() elements into the list because it may cause other elements that have already been inserted to be pushed out of order.

```
items = []
for line in open(filepath, 'r'):
    for c in line:
        if c != '\n':
            i = int(c)
            items.insert(i, calculate(i)) #not working
```

How do I add them in order?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution at http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/bisect/ where similar problem is solved.